# Implementing DbContextOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

In the following code, I don't understand why we addressed `ApplicationDbContext` after `DbContextOptions`

```
namespace SportsStore.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }   

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the definition of base class construction is :

```
 public DbContext([NotNullAttribute] DbContextOptions options);
```

Is **ApplicationDbContext** in above code is an attribute here? or is it a generic type and why we should use a generic type here? because when it comes to implementing the construction in the official documentation  it is mentioned:

> The option to be used by a DbContext . You normally override
>   DbContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionBuilder) or use a
>   DbContextOptionBuilder to create instances of this class ...

and if we want to configure the derived class construction according to the official Microsoft documentation how we should proceed?

Answer (score 1):

This is so that you can use Dependency Injection to instantiate your context, namely, through the `AddDbContext` extension method. In `OnConfiguring` you can check if the `IsConfigured` property to see if the context was configured through the constructor (the `options` parameter) or not. `DbContextOptions<T>` merely extends `DbContextOptions` and brings nothing new, but this way you can see that it is tied to a specific `DbContext`.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.onconfiguring?view=efcore-2.0.